# Pods – How to use a forked repository?

Tags: xcode, github, repository, cocoapods, podfile

I am having issues updating my pod from my forked repository..keep getting:
[!] Unable to find a specification for 'QMChatViewController'.

The story...I have forked a repository, this one:
https://github.com/QuickBlox/QMChatViewController-ios

I have then done some changes, pushed it to my forked repository at github.

Then in my podfile, I changed to:
pod 'QMChatViewController', :git => 'https://github.com/myrepo/QMChatViewController-ios', :commit => '23123123123sha'

Anything I am not doing correctly here? Please advice....

Comment: Tried this too:
pod 'QMChatViewController', :git => 'https://github.com/myrepo/QMChatViewController-ios.git', :commit => '23123123123sha'

Comment: No help? I am very new to pod :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same problem.

QB has 2 pod specs QMCVDevelopment.podspec and PublicCocoaPods/QMChatViewController.podspec. I removed QMCVDevelopment.podspec development and moved QMChatViewController.podspec to root.

Comment: Thanks..and that's it? Do we need to update any details in the podspec?

Comment: Yes, need to set `source` with your forked repo.

Comment: Thank you so much!